# #root and #this in SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

In Spring 3 SpEL, `#this` and `#root` were introduced.

> The variable #root is always defined and refers to the root context
>   object. Although #this may vary as components of an expression are
>   evaluated, #root always refers to the root.

I have gone through the documentation, but I still don't understand what `#root` means (there is no example). Can someone please give me an example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say we have the following code snippet, that fills a list with several prime numbers and defines it as a variable in a SpEL context:

```
// create an array of integers
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
primes.addAll(Arrays.asList(2,3,5,7,11,13,17));

// create parser and set variable 'primes' as the array of integers
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ctx.setVariable("primes", primes);
```

Now, if we want to narrow the list and get all the prime numbers that are > 10, we can use the `?[]` selection operator. The statement would be this one:

```
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("#primes.?[#this>10]");
List<Integer> primesGreaterThanTen = (List<Integer>) expression.getValue(ctx);
```

As you can see, the expression to be evaluated is `#primes.?[#this > 10]`. How does it work ?

- `#primes` refers to the `primes` list.
- The `?[]` selection operator matches every object `i` in the `primes` list which **is not null** and which matches the criteria, given in the brackets. In our example, the criteria is `#this > 10`. `#this` refers to the current evaluation object, which in our example would be the *object from the list that is being checked at the moment for not-null and > 10*.

The result from the evaluation will be a list, containing:

```
[11, 13, 17]
```

---

A SpEL context can have a `#root` variable. Let's have this simple class:

```
public class SomeCustomObject {
    public int stringLength(String input) {
        if (input == null) return 0;
        return input.length();
    }
}
```

and define a instance of our `SomeCustomObject` as the `#root` variable.

```
SomeCustomObject someObject = new SomeCustomObject();
context.setRootObject(someObject);
```

This will create the `someObject` variable a root object for the SpEL context.

A simple example with the `#root` variable.

```
String name = "kocko";
ctx.setVariable("name", kocko);
String statement = "#root.stringLength(#kocko) == 5";
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(statement);

boolean result = expression.getValue(context, Boolean.class);
```

The `result` variable will be evaluated as `true`.

What is the power of the `#root` ?

Through a single root object, you can expose a comprehensive, custom environment to your expressions, for example **custom utility methods and/or variables**.

More info:

- [SpEL expression reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `#this` object changes relative to a portion of the expression during something like a collection projection, but the `#root` object doesn't.

So, if in your context you have two variables: a list of numbers `myNumbers` and a single number `maxNumber`, you can create a projection on that list with a SpEL expression like:

```
myNumbers.?[#this lt #root.maxNumber]
```

Within the projection expression (inside the square brackets), the `#this` object is the item in the collection that's being checked to see if it passes the filter, while the `#root` object is still the variables in the global context.

If you have a list of a more interesting object, like in the [Collection Selection documentation example](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection):

```
Members.?[Nationality == 'Serbian']
```

That "Nationality" is relative to `#this`, the member object. If you wanted to compare against a root context variable instead of a string literal, you'd need to do:

```
Members.?[Nationality == #root.searchedForNationality]
```

If you had just tried `[Nationality == searchedForNationality]` it wouldn't work because `searchedForNationality` isn't part of the member object, but a variable on the root object. You need to use `#root` to qualify it since by default unqualified references are relative to the `#this` object.