# Reference this in Spring's @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-el

I have an abstract controller `ApiRestController` where I declared a common endpoint which delegates the service call to the child class `APICustomRestController`.

```
public abstract class ApiRestController extends BaseRestController {
public static final String TEAMS_ENDPOINT = "/teams";

protected abstract Page<? extends ResponseDto> getTeamsData(int page);
public abstract int getApiCode();

@GetMapping(TEAMS_ENDPOINT)
@PreAuthorize("@aclService.checkAcl(#authentication, #this.getApiCode())")
public Page<? extends ResponseDto> getTeams(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam Optional<Integer> p) {
    return getTeamsData(p.orElse(0));
}
}


@RestController("apiCustomController")
@RequestMapping( API)
public class APICustomRestController extends ApiRestController {
public static final String API = "/custom";
private final TeamDataDtoService teamDataDtoService;

@Autowired
public APICustomRestController(TeamDataDtoService teamDataDtoService) {
    this.teamDataDtoService = teamDataDtoService;
}

@Override
protected Page<? extends ResponseDto> getTeamsData(int page) {
    return teamDataDtoService.getDtoPage(page, 10, "name");
}

@Override
public int getApiCode() {
    return 0; // some key to check authorization
}
}
```

Before the call reaches the service layer, I need to check if the caller does have required authorities to access the endpoint. I have tried `@PreAuthorize("@aclService.checkAcl(#authentication, #this.getApiCode())")`, but IDE gives warning about `#this` as it cannot be resolved. `@aclService` is an actual bean, which checks the authorization and returns a boolean (if I try to put static value e.g. `@PreAuthorize("@aclService.checkAcl(#authentication, 0)")` - that works). With dynamic call to `#this.getApiCode()` in runtime, I get the exception with message:

```
Failed to evaluate expression '@aclService.checkAcl(#authentication, #this.getApiCode())'
```

I have checked the docs, where it says that you can access `#that` or `#root`:

> The variable #this is always defined and refers to the current evaluation object (against which unqualified references are resolved). The variable #root is always defined and refers to the root context object. Although #this may vary as components of an expression are evaluated, #root always refers to the root.

What am I missing here?

Comment: that message is very limited...try things like #this.wrongMethod()... #wrongRef.a()... #getApiCode()... #this instanceof APICustomRestController ? 0 : 1... and see where the error messages lead you

Comment: im no SpEL expert so im not going to provide an answer but i believe that you are misstaking `this` to be the same as in `this` in regular java when in fact it is as the docs says the _current evaluation object_. Which is for instance the object when you are iterating over a list for example. If you want to call a specific function i think have to do a bean lookup there too `'@aclService.checkAcl(#authentication, @apiCustomController.getApiCode())'` but this is just a guess and i cant run any code atm. This post is what im referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442574/1840146

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel@Toerktumlare thanks, figured that out after several hours of research... Had to restructure this code a little to move ```PreAuthorize``` into service layer of child classes which solved the problem. Anyway thanks again for your time

Comment: okey good that things worked out.